# In onTouchEvent, ACTION_UP doesn't work

Tags: android, touch-event

I'd like to read when a player touches the screen, and when not.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){  //ACTION UP
        actionOnUP = true;
        Log.v("MC", "Up");
    }
    if(event.getAction() == 0){ //ACTION DOWN
        actionOnUP = false;
        Log.v("MC", "Down");
    }
    Log.v("MC", event.getAction() + " ");
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This code, yes, it works, but only when player touch the screen (ACTION_DOWN), but when he don't touching the screen (ACTION_UP), nothing happens :/
[image: LogCat]

^ This is screen form LogCat. You can see: this is only ACTION_DOWN, but nothing about ACTION_UP.
Class is extending View:

```
public class MainClass extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
```

Can you help me?

EDIT: My game is based on this tutorial: http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-v,848.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

My guess is that super.onTouchEvent is returning `false`, as whatever superclass you're calling doesn't care about the touch event.

If you return `false` to onTouchEvent, then the Android OS will no longer notify you of any further events in that gesture. If you want to continue receiving touch event information (`ACTION_UP` for example), then you must return `true` to the first `ACTION_DOWN` event.

Comment: It feels sooo good to get a good, complete, informative answer to your problem. :) Thanks @Tim!

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
int action = event.getAction();
int code = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
if (code == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || code == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :/ My game is based on this: http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-v,848.html

Answer (score 2):

"petey"'s solution worked for me !
Except some syntax errors, corrected here :

```
int code = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
if ((code == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) || (code == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) || (code == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)) {
```

Thanks a lot.