# OnTouchListener on an ImageView does not work correctly?

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, android-progressbar

in my app I have an image view (which is a circular and it is surrounded by a progress bar - circular, again). I am attaching an onTouchListener to it because I need to check when the user touches the image view in order to start the progress bar animation and when the user's finger release the image view I need to cancel the progress bar animation. However, for some reason, only the action_down is executed and I don't know why.

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cantDecideContainer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grey_circle_bg"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/perfect_grey_circle"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cant_devide_black_circle_bg"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/perfect_black_circle"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <com.studentsins.lust.UI.CircleProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/cantDecideProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:progress="0"
            app:progressBarThickness="3dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/grey_circle_bg"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grey_circle_bg"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/grey_circle_bg"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/grey_circle_bg"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/grey_circle_bg"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/grey_circle_bg"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code:

```
 private Animator.AnimatorListener progressBarAnimationListener =  new  Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        mCantDecideProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        // Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");
        mCantDecideProgressBar.setProgress(100);
        //mNumSins.setText(numberOfSins+"");
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {}
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {}
};
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            cantDecideProgressAnimator.cancel();
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP canceled");
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            cantDecideProgressAnimator.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN executed");
        }
        return false;
    }
};


mCantDecideGg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cant_devide_black_circle_bg);

    mCantDecideGg.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    mCantDecideProgressBar = (CircleProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.cantDecideProgressBar);
    //set up the project animator to animate the progress bar from 0 to 100
    cantDecideProgressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCantDecideProgressBar, "progress", 0.0f, 100.0f);
    //add the animation listener to the progress animator to check when the progress has started,finished...
    cantDecideProgressAnimator.addListener(progressBarAnimationListener);
    //set the duration of the animation to 1.2 seconds
    cantDecideProgressAnimator.setDuration(1200);
```

Log:

```
03-01 15:28:36.081 24093-24119/com.studentsins.lust I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-01 15:28:38.201 24093-24093/com.studentsins.lust D/MainActivity: ACTION_DOWN executed
03-01 15:28:45.822 24093-24093/com.studentsins.lust D/MainActivity: ACTION_DOWN executed
03-01 15:29:04.651 24093-24093/com.studentsins.lust D/MainActivity: ACTION_DOWN executed
```

Comment: What if you check for Action_Cancel too : if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this answer:
[In onTouchEvent, ACTION_UP doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588263/in-ontouchevent-action-up-doesnt-work)
It seems you should return `true` in the Touch Event.

Comment: Oh, that was very simple! Thank you very much! It worked!

Answer (score 3):

```
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        cantDecideProgressAnimator.cancel();
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP canceled");
        return true;
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        cantDecideProgressAnimator.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN executed");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

};

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, @JeD was first. Appreciate it, though. :)

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev No problem, I hope this help :)